# PHP - problem including header and footer inside my index website

Tags: php, include

I have a problem with including header.php and footer.php on my index.php

The structure of the website is like this.

I have an index.php page and I have also 4 folders which are (about us), (support), (assets), (includes) that they have pages inside those folders. In the (includes) folder I have header.php and footer.php. In my (assets) folder I have 2 folders which are (css), (js). Inside my (css) folder I have my style.css file and in the (js) folder I have my custom.js file.

In my (includes) folder, the header.php file is including the style.css like this. . Moreover, in my (includes) folder the footer.php file is including the custom.js like this.

Furthermore, in my (about us) folder I have about-us.php page. When I use `<?php include "../includes/header.php"; ?>` and `<?php include "../includes/footer.php"; ?>`, it all works normal.

My problem is this. When I try to include header.php or footer.php in my index.php page they do not work. I have tried to include them like `<?php include “/includes/header.php"; ?>` and `<?php include "includes/footer.php"; ?>` but they do not work. I have tried different methods but nothing is working. The problem is that I can include header.php and footer.php in my sub pages which are inside a folder but not in the index.php which is outside a folder. In addition, If i have to make any change to the header or footer I will have to change it twice, one for the index.php which will be hardcoded and one in the header.php or footer.php which are included in the sub pages.

How can I make it so I can include header.php and footer.php from the (includes) in my index.php page and also working on about-us.php page which is inside the (about us) folder ?

Thanks.

Comment: use: `include './includes/header.php';` , note the dot (.) in front of the first forward slash.

Comment: @jibsteroos did not work

Comment: what error message(s) do you get?

Comment: @jibsteroos when I use ur code I do not get an error message but the style.css and custom.js are not working. In addition, when I type this code <?php include "/includes/header.php"; ?> i get this error messages --- Warning: include(/includes/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory-- and also i get this --Warning: include(): Failed opening '/includes/header.php' for inclusion --

Comment: When you say they "don't work" when you call them from index.php, do you mean the header.php and footer.php files don't load, or they don't load the CSS?

Comment: @Stephen the files are loaded but they do not do anything. There is a problem the way I am using header.php inside my sup pages because there I am using ../includes/header.php - mind the ../ . For them to work I have to include the ../ . In my index page it does not work

Comment: So, including header.php from index.php using `include './includes/header.php` works(no errors), but then your style.css and custom.js do not 'work'? How do you reference these files from index.php?

Comment: @jibsteroos In my index.php I am hardcoding everything. For example <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">. That is working. However in my includes/header.php when I am calling the <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css"> I am calling it with ../ in front, like this <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/style.css"> in order to work in all sup pages.

Comment: That's normal behaviour?  In your index.php file, you are already in your document route, so assets/css/etc .. is fine.  You header.php file needs to get back to document root before it can start going up again, hence the ../ ... when you "include" header.php, header.php will look for the css file relative to itself, not relative to the page you called it from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing files is difficult [non-intuative (pick a word)] when you are bouncing around different levels of a folder structure.  You could write a book on relative and absolute file paths.

If might be better, before your site gets too big to create yourself a config.php file, define a proper base URL for your site, and then include that in each of your pages, along with that, that you are trying to reference.

For example.  In the root directory of your site, create a file called config.php and use the following:

```
<?php
define("ROOT_PATH", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
```

Then in ALL of your other files, you can reference the config.php file first, which will define the ROOT_PATH for that document, and then call your other files.

So in your header.php file

```
<?php 
include "./config.php";
include(ROOT_PATH . "/assets/css/style.css");
```

Then when you call header.php from index.php, header.php will have the absolute route to the CSS file to reference.

I hope I have explained that well enough.

EDIT / ADDITION:
config.php files are a handy addition to any PHP project for many other things as well as defining URLS.  You can keep your DB connections in there, arrays of static things you use often etc.  They become the "go to" place for consistently used things.

Comment: Thank you I will try it

Answer (score -1):

This will work.

`include "./includes/header.php";`

Otherwise, you can include the full file path location of the `header.php` and `footer.php` in the `index.php`

Comment: The OP doesn't need help including his header file, the header file isn't referencing the other files in his directory structure.